# How to make cave pieces modular so they are seamless?

Tags: modeling

Am trying to reduce the amount of cave models by trying to make them modular, but am not sure how to do the in between of them so they look seamless.

I have 2 cave objects (of many) in this image, I want to somehow make them modular so that I can reuse them.

These caves pieces will be low poly and UV texturing isn't important as they will likely just be a single color.  These will be used in a game engine.

[image]

Comment: If you want to make objects modular enable Snapping to Grid (in Blender 2.79 Shift+Tab > default option). Then adjust the mesh so it can be stacked one to another without going out of the grid

Comment: With this kind of topology, will 'Bridge Edge Loops'do the job, even without a matched vertex count? .. that would allow flexibility with orientation..

Comment: @RobinBetts I did try that, and it works pretty well.  Still not quite sure what I am doing, but am getting closer I think :P

Comment: @RobinBetts Just following up.  Bridging helped solve this issue.  I bridged between the object and a connector that was always the same amount of verts on either end so that I could always connect them up no matter what.  Ty.

Comment: .. a sort of 'cave adaptor' ... cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the vertices at each connection pint to be perfect matches for each other, and you need them to have the same uv coordinates. These are nontrivial tasks, but I do have a few recommendations:

First, consider working without a subsurf. That way you can have all cave entrances and exits be exact copies of each other.

Second, uv unwrap a cave segment with the maximum number of exits intended first, then make all subsequent caves start as duplicates. Unwrap these but pin the verts of the exits when doing so.

Finally, make sure you have exact coordinates and angles for all exits relative to each other so that your game engine can get them into place.

I have never done this, but it sounds plausible!

Comment: I'll be honest, most of this went over my head.  Am still trying to learn Blender.  I edited my question.  I will be dealing with low poly caves and UV texturing won't be an issue as they will likely be a single color.

Comment: After a few weeks of learning a little more about Blender, I managed to create modular sections.  I didn't care about UV stuff, all I needed to worry about is getting each end to be identical.